# How to debug Rust with LLDB in Doom Emacs?

Tags: doom

I have tried [this tutorial](https://gagbo.net/post/dap-mode-rust/) to setup debug for rust in doom emacs, but I when I loaded my vscodium generated launch.json I get the message `Have you loaded the 'lldb' specific package?` and nothing more happens. Thus realized that it is for rust-gdb and not for lldb, [doom emacs](https://docs.doomemacs.org/v21.12/modules/tools/debugger/) config is little to no helpful, and [dap-mode](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/dap-mode/page/configuration/) documentation even less helpful given that their lldb instruction settings are wrong beacuse they don't install the lldb specific package given the persistence of the error message.

My currrent `~/.config/doom/config.el` being

```
(after! dap-mode
  (setq dap-cpptools-extension-version "1.5.1")

  (require 'dap-lldb)

  (with-eval-after-load 'lsp-rust
    (require 'dap-cpptools))
    (with-eval-after-load 'dap-cpptools)

  (with-eval-after-load 'dap-mode
    (setq dap-default-terminal-kind "integrated") ;; Make sure that terminal programs open a term for I/O in an Emacs buffer
    (dap-auto-configure-mode +1)))
```

And my current `~/.config/doom/packages.el` containing

```
(package! lldb-vscode)
```

And the error persits.

Note I have (dap-mode +lsp) in my `~/.config/doom/init.el`
Note I have no vscode implementations installed in my system, and don't want to.